# Pagination / Array and query

Tags: php, arrays, pagination

Very new to PHP and Mysql and am attempting to help son with a project that requires a form submission with checkboxes which queries a specific column in database table named "item_id" which contains incremental integers.

We have successfully created an array with check boxes named "category" and using an implode like this:

```
$categories = implode(",",$_GET['category']);
```

we can query the database using this

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clients 
                     WHERE upper($field) LIKE'%$find%' AND item_id IN ($categories)
                     ORDER BY item_updated DESC LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage;");
```

This works great and we can echo the output which seems to work well and contain multiple categories depending on which checboxes were selected.

We also have a count query in there to generate a row count and generate some pagination which we implemented via a tutorial script which also works.

The problem we're having is that the pagination links work fine if all records are returned from the database, but to paginate the results of a search with multiple categories from the implode, I am calling the script from the echo'd `<a href=` links again with all of the appropriate search strings but when I try to include the categories, they are not being recognized because I assume I am trying to implode an array which doesn't exist.

I.e if my code for a particular pagination link looks like

```
echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=1&find=$find&category=$categories'><<</a> ";
```

The resultant category part of the link looks like category=5,2 for instance and when clicked on, returns no results.  I assume this is because I am trying to implode 5,2 instead of a form submitted array.

If anyone could shed some light on what I need to do to get this working, it would be much appreciated.  Not sure whether I need to have another string that's not imploded to begin with or use arrayslice etc. to get around it. Have read as much as I can get my head around without being successful.

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attack, and use deprecated `mysql_*` functions. You should use prepared statments instead.

Comment: Investigating prepared statements and mitigating injection attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the way you are building your hyperlink, it seems that $_GET['category'] will only be a string.

If you were to have your categories presented as &category[]=5&category[]=2, you will receive it as an array.

But the simplest hack in your case would be to **NOT** use implode at all. As $_GET['category'] will already return "5,2" as a string. (Consider [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php))

It might be a bit too much to consume for now, but also consider using [prepared statements](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp).

---

**Edit:**
Based on your comment, it appears you want to maintain using an array for categories.

I will give you two ways of achieving that.

---

The first way takes your use of hyperlinks into consideration:

```
$categories = [];
foreach($_GET['category'] as $cat)
{
    array_push($categories, 'category[]=' + urlencode($cat));
}

echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=1&find=$find&" 
. implode('&',$categories) . "'>&lt;&lt;</a> ";
```

To those asking "Why not use http_build_query?": An associative array can only have one occurrence of a specific key.

---

The second way would be to have a form with `method="get"` and `action="{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}"`

Then you would echo all your categories as hidden inputs

```
$categories = [];
foreach($_GET['category'] as $cat)
{
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="category" value="' . htmlentities($cat) . '"/>'
}
```

and then having buttons `input type="submit" value="1" name="currentpage"`
The web browser will then build the url for you.
The cool thing about forms are that input types like checkboxes and submits won't be sent to the server unless the user interacts with them

Comment: Thank-you - will investigate prepared statements.  I tried removing the implode function before  $_GET['category'] but if I do this and then echo $categories I just get "array" displaying in the browser.

If I keep the implode there and echo it I do see the following structure 5,2 and with my query get only results using both those category numbers. The browser also displays &category[]=5&category[]=2 in the URL bar.

Is there a way to maintain the &category[]=5&category[]=2 structure from a hyperlink or can this only be done from a form post?

Comment: About an hour ago I finally hacked a solution that worked by running a different query based on whether I was initially submitting the form or clicking on the pagination links.  I created a variable in the links that gets set to 1 when they are clicked on and 0 when the form is submitted.  Doing this I was able to get around the implode statement when pagination links were clicked. Your solution is much more elegant and also works so will incorporate this fully if I can when I get time.  Thanks a million for your time and expertise.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using the examples I gave you to build a final solution, but rather use it as stepping stones to eventually get to a point where you have tables that can page and filter via ajax. I would say you are right on track as you are seeing the fundamental mechanics i.e. post vs get, how data looks on the server vs client etc.